# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given string value: [] cannot be transformed to Json object

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I got error like this.

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given string value: [{"id": "DFW", "namd": "Dallas, TX (DFW-Dallas-Fort Worth Intl.)", "name_kr": "댈러스, 텍사스 (DFW-댈러스-포트워스 국제공항)"}, {"id": "DAL", "namd": "Dallas, TX (DAL-Love Field)", "name_kr": "댈라스, 텍사스 (DAL-러브필드 공항)"}, {"id": "RBD", "namd": "Dallas, TX (RBD-Executive)", "name_kr": "댈러스, 텍사스 (RBD-이그제큐티브)"}, {"id": "ADS", "namd": "Dallas, TX (ADS-Addison)", "name_kr": "댈러스, 텍사스 (ADS-애디슨 공항)"}] cannot be transformed to Json object

this value is my jsonb column of postgres row.

and here is my table entity sample (related problem).

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "expedia_region_union")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class ExpediaRegionUnion {


    @Id
//    @GeneratedValue
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column( columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false )
    private String regionId;


    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "airport")
    private HashMap airport;



    @Column(name = "source_time")
    private String sourceTime;
```

In my opinion, the entity map doesn't seem to handle the airport field.
the `airport` field is list as jsonb type.
but I made entity rule like `HashMap`.

sample data

```
about airport field

[
  {
    "id": "DFW",
    "namd": "Dallas, TX (DFW-Dallas-Fort Worth Intl.)",
    "name_kr": "댈러스, 텍사스 (DFW-댈러스-포트워스 국제공항)"
  },
  {
    "id": "DAL",
    "namd": "Dallas, TX (DAL-Love Field)",
    "name_kr": "댈라스, 텍사스 (DAL-러브필드 공항)"
  },
  {
    "id": "RBD",
    "namd": "Dallas, TX (RBD-Executive)",
    "name_kr": "댈러스, 텍사스 (RBD-이그제큐티브)"
  },
  {
    "id": "ADS",
    "namd": "Dallas, TX (ADS-Addison)",
    "name_kr": "댈러스, 텍사스 (ADS-애디슨 공항)"
  }
]
```

[image]

How do I change the entity settings?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is not matching your expectations.

```
"airport" : "[{\"id\": \"DFW\", \"namd\": \"Dallas, TX (DFW-Dallas-Fort Worth Intl.)\", \"name_kr\": \"댈러스, 텍사스 (DFW-댈러스-포트워스 국제공항)\"}, ...]"
```

is not an array but a String, shown by the quotes around the value. A valid JSON array would look like

```
"airport" : [{"id": "DFW", "namd": "Dallas, TX (DFW-Dallas-Fort Worth Intl.)", "name_kr": "댈러스, 텍사스 (DFW-댈러스-포트워스 국제공항)"}, {"id": "DAL", "namd": "Dallas, TX (DAL-Love Field)", "name_kr": "댈라스, 텍사스 (DAL-러브필드 공항)"}, {"id": "RBD", "namd": "Dallas, TX (RBD-Executive)", "name_kr": "댈러스, 텍사스 (RBD-이그제큐티브)"}, {"id": "ADS", "namd": "Dallas, TX (ADS-Addison)", "name_kr": "댈러스, 텍사스 (ADS-애디슨 공항)"}]
```

Comment: thank you for response. but I think the data is not problem. so I edited my sample data. because when I see the `airport field` in postgres using dbeaver, it seems like right type i mean jsonb. it's not string type. if it's string, dbeaver doesn't fold. (you can see this picture above)

Comment: I don't think it's because of what you said, but jpa doesn't work because jsonb data is an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "airport")
    private List airport;
```

I solved this so simply, I don't know if I can help someone.

edit -> jsonb as a list.